# What is the meaning of hyphen in cargo test's outputs?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I ran cargo test with the following command

```
RUST_LOG=debug LOG_LEVEL=debug RUST_BACKTRACE=full cargo test --package tests --test failpoints cases::test_snap
```

I only have one `test_concurrent_snapshot` defined in tests/failpoints/cases/test_snap.rs. However, in output there are output `test_concurrent_snapshot-0` and `test_concurrent_snapshot`. I don't know what is the meaning of `-0`?

```
test_concurrent_snapshot-0 2022/08/26 11:39:15.548 pd.rs:1697: [DEBG] executing task, task: auto split split regions, num is 0
test_concurrent_snapshot-0 2022/08/26 11:39:15.548 snap.rs:1705: [DEBG] register snapshot, entry: Applying, key: 1_6_10
test_concurrent_snapshot-0 2022/08/26 11:39:15.549 snap.rs:736: [INFO] set_snapshot_meta total cf files count: 3
test_concurrent_snapshot 2022/08/26 11:39:15.553 peer.rs:2269: [DEBG] still applying snapshot, skip further handling, peer_id: 3, region_id: 1
test_concurrent_snapshot 2022/08/26 11:39:15.564 peer.rs:2269: [DEBG] still applying snapshot, skip further handling, peer_id: 3, region_id: 1
```

Comment: are you using the `insta` crate?

Comment: Usually when you run a test and set its name (say foo), cargo runs all the tests that starts with foo unless you specify the path (bar::foo for example). Still, I believe we need more context